# Sp_WhoIsActive doubles reads for same query

Tags: sql-server

we had a lot of times that our SQL server maxed out, we are then using sp_who_is_Active to see what's causing the trouble, its very perplexing because we see the same query with a million reads but the other lines same query can have like 10 million reads or 100 million reads and its all same query and presumably same parameters. what does that mean?

Comment: sp_whoisactive tells you about the state of sessions right now. The executions you are seeing may have started at different times and that is just what they've read up to so far, all it tells you is that the execution needs to read at least that much data. There are reasons why some executions will do less work (caching, actual data changes, come to mind) but it's unlikely to cause as much of a difference as you're noting.

Comment: "... And presumably the same parameters." Say more about this assumption. I would assume exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `sp_WhoIsActive` will show you how many reads the query has done *so far.*

If I run this query (which will result in a lot of reads):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.messages m1
CROSS JOIN sys.messages m2;
```

And then wait a few seconds, run the exact same query in a different SSMS window, here's what `sp_WhoIsActive` shows me:

[image: screenshot of sp_WhoIsActive output]
*Note: I hid a bunch of the columns that were irrelevant to this Q&A*

Session 61 has performed 1,022,683 reads, with a start time of 09:56:22.
Session 67 has performed 561,601 reads, with a start time of 09:56:33.

These two queries would eventually perform the same number of reads (they are the same, and using the same execution plan in this case).  But it would be hard to catch that in `sp_WhoIsActive` because of the "snapshot" nature of the output.

Assuming the parameters for your queries are the same, as you stated, check the start_time to confirm that they are showing different counts for "reads" because they started at different times.

---

If the parameters are not the same, then that could also explain the differing amounts of reads.  Different parameters will read different amounts of data as required by the query, and might even result in completely different execution plans.